# "This file is hidden" when uploading folder to GitHub

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

This is not a .gitignore error. I'm trying to upload a `contrib` folder that doesn't yet exist in my repository. At first, I tried committing through VScode, which wouldn't detect the file change. Then, I tried to upload via command line with `git add .`, a commit, and a push. No changes were detected. I deleted the folder, then tried to commit that, but still git doesn't detect any changes. Has anyone experienced this issue?

This folder isn't empty.

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository

Comment: @JackTing Probably should've clarified this, but it's not an empty directory

Comment: So, what's your `compat` folder ?

Comment: on using this : `git add .`. were you getting any error like this : `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: @JackTing My bad, it's a `contrib`. And for some reason the copy I had was empty. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Subfolders were empty for some reason. Solved.